# Windows not reporting correct used and available disk space on Samba server with ZFS

Tags: linux, rhel, windows, samba, zfs

I have a Samba server running ZFS in Linux.

- It is a standard by-the-book install with no special configuration.
- Each share is mapped to their own ZFS dataset, but not all datasets have their own share.

`Oracle Linux 9.2`
`ZFS 2.1.12`
`Samba 4.17.5`

I used [this dfree script](https://stanislavs.org/reporting-correct-space-usage-for-samba-shared-zfs-volumes/#comment-81) to get windows to report the proper used and free space remaining in File Explorer:

```
#!/bin/bash
USED=$((`zfs get -o value -Hp used $1` / 1024)) > /dev/null
AVAIL=$((`zfs get -o value -Hp available $1` / 1024)) > /dev/null
TOTAL=$(($USED+$AVAIL)) > /dev/null
echo -ne $TOTAL $AVAIL
```

This works as intended.

However this is creating confusion to end users: they see the reported capacities for the different shares are slightly different, assume this means they must be different servers, and call me asking why that is.

So I want Windows to report the used space and capacity of the **entire ZFS pool** regardless of the share, rather than the reported used and available space of the individual datasets their shares are mapped to.

In theory I should simply replace $1 with the name of the pool ("tank" in this case), however the reported disk space does not change in windows:

```
#!/bin/bash
USED=$((`zfs get -o value -Hp used tank` / 1024)) > /dev/null
AVAIL=$((`zfs get -o value -Hp available tank` / 1024)) > /dev/null
TOTAL=$(($USED+$AVAIL)) > /dev/null
echo -ne $TOTAL $AVAIL
```

[image]

Various tinkering causes Windows to either report strange values or nothing at all.

The only way I found to make this work so far is to hardcode USED and AVAIL to be what the zfs get commands are supposed to return:

```
#!/bin/bash
USED=11258621113
AVAIL=28766985099
TOTAL=$(($USED+$AVAIL)) > /dev/null
echo -ne $TOTAL $AVAIL
```

[image]

Am I missing something silly? Has anyone got this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on what metrics you want to show users, you may want to use the `referenced` property of the filesystem (to show actual disk space used), or even `logicalreferenced` (to show the total amount of user data that has been compressed down) in place of the `used` property.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I regret I do not have a solution for you, because I can't reproduce your problem.  I have never used a `dfree command` directive in `smb.conf` in over a dozen Samba instances on FreeBSD machines, and have never had the problem you describe.  Samba seems to know how to query the disk space stats, and Windows reports reasonable disk utilization metrics.  For a filesystem with:

```
$ zfs list -Hpo used,avail tank/r2d2
2209625051136   1605933772800
```

Windows shows: 1.45TB free out of 3.32TB

I am not qualified to say for sure, but the root problem of Samba not being able to determine sane numbers may lie in a defect somewhere in the upstream integration of ZFS and Samba.  At the very least, Samba ought to be able to find the ZFS filesystem's `used` and `avail` properties, as you are trying to do by hand.  All my systems figure this out just fine on their own.

But at a more fundamental level, your post suggests that you realize, though
your users may not, that ZFS is something of a paradigm shift in disk
storage.  One telling hint is that you're having to calculate the "Total"
capacity of the filesystem.  ZFS itself doesn't have this concept (at the
filesystem level), and indeed, there is no `size` property that can be
accessed by the `zfs list` utility.

At the filesystem level, the `used` vs. `available` numbers will always be
squishy, because the data itself is squishy.  ZFS filesystems can be (and
often are) configured to compress data on-the-fly, without the user being
aware of that.  So a user might see a volume with 100G available, save a compressible 10G file, and then be baffled when instead of dropping to 90G free, the volume still has 95G free.  They'll wonder how the server's disk array seemingly stored a 10G file, but the "available" space decreased by only 5GB.  It's because **the compression is transparent to the user**.

Another way to put it: take a generic 4TB drive.  What is its "capacity"?
The subset of your users who call you asking about disk space will probably
say "four terabytes."  But in ZFS, that's the physical capacity, the amount of hard disk space, a *minimum* number, and is true
only in the case where the data is incompressible.  If your data is compressible, then the total **logical** capacity of the drive (which may be what your users think of when they ask "How much more storage do we have?") is likely higher than 4 TB.  Even using the old `lz4`
compression algorithm, I have filesystems that exceed 3x compression, one
reaching almost 6x.  At that rate the "4 TB" drive's capacity would be
between 12 and 24 terabytes.  With `zstd` compression, the compression ratios
can go to double digits.

The difficulty is that, while ZFS knows what the compression ratio of the *stored* data is (`used` vs. `logicalused`), there is no way to determine how compressible the "available" space is until data is actually written to it.  In other words, `total=used+avail` breaks because although `used` is known, `avail` is only a minimum.  `total` could actually be more than `used+avail`, depending on what your future data storage patterns are.

In ZFS *filesystems*, there is no such thing as "disk capacity" except in
the context of the actual data that is going to be stored.  When a filesystem with a known `available` value stores additional data,
say a file 10G in size, it could compress at 2:1 to consume only 5G of the actual disk.  So saving a compressible 10G file could cause the logical capacity to go up by 5GB.  Storing that 10G of data caused your apparent "capacity" to go up by 5 GB.  This is why your users are confused.  They don't understand that a drive with a nominal **physical** capacity of 4TB could increase to a **logical** capacity of 8TB of actual user data, if the user data is 2:1 compressible.  Tracking the amount of `available` or `total` space in a compressible filesystem is always going to be a shifting target.

IMO you're on the right track when you say that you want to shift to
reporting disk space metrics at the pool level.  That is what I do in my uptime monitoring system, because regardless of the compression level, the
output from `zpool` always reflects the actual numbers of bytes that are used (`allocated`) or not used (`size`-`allocated`) on the drive.  Indeed, at the pool level is where we finally find a
"Size" property, something ZFS filesystems don't have.  The amount used and
amount available are slightly less meaningful, notably because they reflect
RAID-Z parity, but the ratio of used/size is generally accurate:

```
$ zpool list -po cap,alloc,size
  CAP          ALLOC           SIZE
   56  2256319561728  3985729650688
$ bc <<< 'scale=4; 2256319561728/3985729650688'
.5660
```

Most people can understand that the disk is "56% full" or "92% full."  But when they ask, "how much more data can we store?" the answer can only be "It depends."

Please update your post as you arrive closer to your preferred solution.  I realize all I've posted here doesn't address your question directly, but I wanted to illustrate the fact that the difficulty you're facing is rooted as much or more in user education as it is in technical methods.

Answer (score -1):

In Samba, the disk space reporting for shares is typically done at the share level, not at the pool level. This is why you are seeing slightly different reported capacities for each share, as they correspond to the properties of the individual datasets.

If you want Windows to report the used space and capacity of the entire ZFS pool, you may need to consider an alternative approach, as modifying the behavior of Samba's disk space reporting for individual shares can be complex and might not yield the desired results.

One possible approach is to create a separate share that points to the root of the ZFS pool (e.g., `/tank`) and then use that share for reporting the pool-level disk space. Here's how you could do it:

1. Create a share that points to the ZFS pool's root directory in your Samba configuration file (usually `/etc/samba/smb.conf`). You can do this by adding a new section like this:

   ```ini
   [pool-root]
   path = /tank
   read only = yes
   browseable = no
   ```

   Adjust the path (`/tank`) to match your ZFS pool's mount point.
2. Restart the Samba service to apply the configuration changes:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl restart smbd
   ```
3. Access the `pool-root` share from Windows, and it should report the disk space for the entire ZFS pool.

Please note that by creating this special share, users will be able to access the root of the ZFS pool, so make sure to set appropriate permissions and restrictions to limit access if necessary.

Keep in mind that this approach does not modify how individual share-level reporting works in Samba. It simply provides an additional share that points to the pool's root for reporting purposes.